# Is there a programmatic way of determining which process is playing sound on Windows XP?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, windows-xp, wasapi

My question is very similar to this one: [Peak meters for individual programs on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313692/peak-meters-for-individual-programs-on-windows-7/14367829#14367829)

I'm also trying to write a program to enumerate all processes currently playing sound. But in my case I need it to work also on Windows XP, and the answer I found here doesn't work for me because WASAPI wasn't introduced until Windows Vista.