# Capturing a single application's audio with Win32

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, audio-capture

How would I go about capturing the audio output of a single application with Win32/C++/C#, whilst avoiding hooking against `IAudioRenderClient`?

I have only been able to find solutions to capture the whole audio output of the system (or rather, the currently active audio output port / capture device), either through DirectShow or various other Win32 API functions (WASAPI etc.) which were of little help (because I only need a single applications audio output). The only viable solution seemed to be hooking the applications IAudioRenderClient and then calling `IAudioRenderClient::GetBuffers()` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084550/capture-audio-of-a-single-application-on-windows-7).

The reason I am trying to avoid this is that a majority of applications I intend to capture are protected by various anti-cheat systems, able to detect the code injection but unable to differentiate it from an actual cheat.

Any pointers towards APIs/API-functions etc. or anything silencing my concerns of false detection would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah - that's WHY the "majority of applications [you] intend to capture are protected by various anti-cheat systems." Danged copwrite laws. Who needs 'em?

Comment: You will have to hook. And most likely not just `IAudioRenderClient` but all audio APIs the applications in question use.